# Application of Exchange sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, exchange-server

What are some application of Exchange sort algorithm? Where is this algorithm used and what are its advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: What "exchange sort" are you talking about? Some people call the [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) "Exchange sort." But there is a general class of sorting algorithms called exchange sorts (Bubblesort, Quick sort, Bogosort, etc.). There's also the [Radix exchange sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. there are. Depending on your required criteria of the sorting you might want to use different algorithms.

Here some possible criteria:

- you want the average fasted sorting for input data with unknown or random order
- you need to ensure O(n log n) speed
- you need in place sorting
- you cannot store the whole data in memory
- ...